# Magento 2 js not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

On one of my websites, sometimes some of my customs js not working, I have embedded them on a template file. I have checked the console of the browser it shows an error, also sometimes CSS or some portion like sign-in/sign out or logo will not display.

to fix it I have to run content deploy every time, I just need to know the root cause of it. What will be the best practices to fix this kind of issue, so that I don't have to run content deploy every time, as the website is already live, and it seems very disappointing if suddenly some function stop working.

Also, I have noticed that content deploy is not working with -f is that was also an issue, which brings these problems.

Thanks

Comment: Which mode you are using ?

Comment: currently its development mode.

Comment: have you added JS code to phtml  file ? Please also share what code you have added ?

Comment: yes i did it in on template file. It was a plain js script for validating form nothing else. script is working fine without throwing any error on console logs.

Answer (score 1):

> **Please try the steps as described below.**

I assume Magento is on Developer mode while you follow the below steps.

**step 1)**  Please Go  to Admin panel and navigate to
**STORES** -> **Configuration** -> **ADVANCED** -> **DEVELOPER** .

Click on "**JavaScript Settings**" to expand it.

**Step 2)** Please set JavaScript Settings as follows:

- Merge JavaScript Files        : Yes
- Enable JavaScript Bundling    : No
- Minify JavaScript Files       : No

**Step 3)**
Run Following CLI commands from your Magento 2 root directory to remove static files, generated files, cache files.

```
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/generated/*
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

**step 4:**) Again please run the below CLI commands to set Production mode

```
sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Step 5)** Run the below commands to set permission to the pub, var, and generated folder

```
sudo chmod -Rv 777 pub var generated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the static-deploy in verbose mode with -vvv and that might show more output assuming its hitting an error when your custom JS is not there.